# Calling a method in parent scene from a menu in a child Layer cocos2d

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I am adding a layer (hudLayer) to my gamePlay scene, and then adding a menu to that layer from which I want to run a function `- (void) pauseGame {
method in here }`

I'm trying to implement this like so:

```
- (void) addPauseButton: (CCScene *) parent {
pauseButton = [CCMenuItemImage itemWithNormalImage:@"pause.png" selectedImage:nil target:parent selector:@selector(pauseGame:)];
pause = [CCMenu menuWithItems:pauseButton, nil];
[hudLayer addChild: pause];
if (device == @"iPad") {
    pause.position = ccp(40,40);
}
else if (device == @"iPhoneFive") {
    pause.position = ccp(290,30);
}
else {
    pause.position = ccp(290,30);
}
}

- (id)init {

if( (self=[super init])) {
    paused = FALSE;
    CGSize screenSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;

    hudLayer = [[[CCLayer alloc] init] autorelease];
    [self addChild:hudLayer z:2]; // adds hudLayer

    gameLayer = [[[CCLayer alloc] init] autorelease];
    [self addChild:gameLayer z:1];

    pauseMenu = [[[CCLayer alloc] init] autorelease];
    [self addChild:pauseMenu z:4];

    [self setupWorld];
    [self addPauseButton:self];   //calls method to add pause button to hudLayer sending it the scene as a variable

    CGPoint offScreenPoint = ccp(screenSize.width+(screenSize.width/2), 0);

    pauseMenu.position = offScreenPoint;

    self.motionManager = [[[CMMotionManager alloc] init] autorelease];
    motionManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 1.0/60.0;
    if (motionManager.isDeviceMotionAvailable) {
        [motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdates];
    }
    self.iPadBool = UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad;

    if (iPadBool) {
        device = @"iPad";
    }
    else if (screenSize.height > 490) {
        device = @"iPhoneFive";
    }
    else {
        device = @"iPhone";
    }
    NSLog(@"the current device is a, %@", device);
    [self schedule:@selector(update:)];

}
return self;
}
```

However this throws the error: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[gamePlay pauseGame:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x11d310e0' No idea why at all :/ any idea's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The selector should be

```
@selector(pauseGame)
```

without the colon. It doesn't take a parameter. Method should be:

```
-(void) pauseGame
{
}
```

Comment: yep, the colons means parameters, so for your example it couldn't find that selector with one parameter.